# Laravel9 (PHP) Latest Owl carousel 2 not displaying image on page

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel-9, owl-carousel-2

Hi I trying to use owl carousel from https://owlcarousel2.github.io/

but owl carousel not displaying anything. I already check the css and js. I have include all the source but still the same. And I do not know is that js and css working properly or not. I also rearrange js file in my page. By the way, the data is there but when I put inside the owl carousel class nothing show.

```html
<div class="owl-carousel featured-carousel owl-theme">
  ............
  ............
</div>
```

I have inspect in chrome browser and not getting error. I have include the page and my js and css folder.

**web page**

[image: web page]

**css and js folder**

[image: css and js folder]

Here my code.

#### front.blade.php

```php
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
        <!-- CSRF Token -->
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    
        <title>
            @yield('title')
        </title>
        <!-- plugins:css -->
        <link href="{{ asset('frontend/css/custom.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="{{ asset('frontend/css/bootstrap5.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- endinject -->
        <link href="{{ asset('frontend/css/owl.carousel.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="{{ asset('frontend/css/owl.theme.default.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
        @include('layouts.inc.frontnavbar')
    
        <div class="content-wrapper">
    
            @yield('content')
    
        </div>
    
    
    
        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="{{ asset('frontend/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js') }}"></script>
        <!-- plugins:js -->
        <script src="{{ asset('frontend/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('frontend/js/owl.carousel.min.js') }}"></script>
        <!-- endinject -->
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
        @if (session('status'))
            <script>
                swal("{{ session('status') }}");
            </script>
        @endif
    
    
        @yield('script')
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

#### index.blade.php

```php
@extends('layouts.front')

@section('title')
    Welcome to E-Commerce
@endsection

@section('content')
    @include('layouts.inc.slider')

    <div class="py-5">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="owl-carousel featured-carousel owl-theme">
                    @foreach ($featured_products as $prod)
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="card ">
                            <img src="{{ asset('assets/uploads/products/'.$prod->image) }}" alt="Product image">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5>{{ $prod->name }}</h5>
                                <small>{{ $prod->selling_price }}</small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection

@section('scripts')
<script>
    $('.featured-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    }
})
</script>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `yield` and `section` names do not match, which means that your call to initiate the Owl Carousel is not being outputted to the view.

This is what you have:

```
@yield('script')
```

```
@section('scripts')
```

Change it to:

```
@yield('scripts')
```

```
@section('scripts')
```

#### Stacks

You can also use [stacks](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#stacks). These are more useful for appending resources to the view as you can push many times e.g. from child views or components.

You would change your yield method to

```
@stack('scripts')
```

and then your section method to:

```
@push('scripts')
<script>
    $('.featured-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    }
})
</script>
@endpush
```

Comment: Oh thank you sir. How terrible am I not notice that mistake. Sure I will use your suggestion.